# Convert screen coordinates into bitmap coordinates

Tags: c, bitmap

I have a screen resoultion of 320*240. and an Image for example 180*180.

I would like to convert a position 120,120 for example into the bitmap coordinates, so that it's placed correctly on the 320*240 screen coordinates.

Here is my attempt

```
// w, h width and height of an image
// position x,y on the screen coordinates

void Rasterizer::DrawBitmap(int w, int h, int x, int y, float angle)
{ 
    uint16_t pixel;

    float relx = w/ (float)320;
    float rely = h/ (float)240;
    uint16_t xgoal = (x * relx) + w/2;
    uint16_t ygoal = (y * rely) + h/2;

    float midX, midY;
    float deltaX, deltaY;
    int rotX, rotY;
    int i, j;
    midX = w / 2.0f;
    midY = h / 2.0f;
    for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            deltaX = i - midX;
            deltaY = j - midY;
            rotX = (int)(midX + deltaX * sin(angle) + deltaY * cos(angle));
            rotY = (int)(midY + deltaX * cos(angle) - deltaY * sin(angle));
            if (rotX >= 0 && rotX < w && rotY >= 0 && rotY < h) {
                SetPixel(xgoal + i,ygoal +j , bitmap[(rotX*w + rotY )]);
            }
        }

}
```

[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W109t.png)

Comment: Give us an example with inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: @ThomasJager I already did, screen resolution 320*240, 180*180 image, position 120,120. I need to map 120,120 into the bitmap coordinates and renders it on the screen at 120,120

Comment: What doesn't work about what you've done? In what way does it not work?

Comment: The placement of the image using the above equations, doesn't work as expected, there are a lot of offsets there, for example If I'm centing the bitmap into the center of the screen, it's offseted to the right

Comment: What do you mean by "placed correctly"? What does the image size have to do with where it is placed? At 1:1 it will overflow the bottom of the screen. Are you asking how to scale it so it fits? It also depends on whether screen pixels are "square" and they are frequently not (for reasons best known to the designers). The screen from 120 to bottom is 120 pixels. So the 180x180 image has to be scaled by 2/3.

Comment: I'm not talking about scaling, I'm talking about translating an image into screen. I'm drawing the bitmap manually, for each row, col, draw pixel. so I want to translate it correctly

Comment: float??? What do you want to do with float and pixels?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: If you're translating, why the angle?

Comment: translate then rotate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw image in the center of screen then you need to translate all the pixel. Assuming top left corner of the screen is (0,0)

```
    uint16_t relx = 320/2 - w/2 ;
    uint16_t rely = 240/2 - h/2;
    uint16_t xgoal = relx + x;
    uint16_t ygoal = rely + y;
```

Comment: I put x,y at the center of the screen (320,240) but its drawn as this in the post

Comment: What is the output if you just draw it without translating

Comment: with 0,0 x,y,  xgoal = 67, ygoal = 27.. image is 186*186, screen resolution 320*240

Comment: and with 0,0 its centered in the middle... which means the origin is shifted to the center of the screen.. which that I don't want

Comment: Can you verify that if you draw something on the screen at 0,0 it would be on top left.

Comment: I verified it, without the translating code, Its set to 0,0

Comment: Just do it step by step, you would figure it out. First try translation. If that worked then move to rotation. Translation is just adding some constant to x or y. Should be pretty straight forward. Try just constant values to move the image.

Comment: here is it without rotation, https://pastebin.com/hcygg9jE
it still at 0,0 it moves the bitmap into origin, instead of top left

Comment: What is x and y here. Is this is a point where you want to start putting a image on screen

Comment: you are adding x and y to xgoal and ygoal and then again adding i and j to it. You dont need x and y. Just set it to zero. In this case image should appear in center